# Wayfire does not work on FreeBSD 14.0?

Tags: xorg, freebsd, nvidia, desktop-environment, wayland

Ehy bro',

I'm trying to install wayfire watching the tutorial below,at minute : 21:07

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVNC1z016M8&t=1267s

because I would like to install wayland / wayfire on my FreeBSD 14.0,but it does not work for me (my graphic card is one nvidia GTX 1060).

When I did :

```
rot@marietto:/usr/home/marietto # wayfire -c ./config/wayfire/wayfire.ini 

II 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - [src/main.cpp:334] Starting 
wayfire version v0.8.0 

II 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - [backend/x11/backend.c:395] 
Creating X11 backend 

II 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - [backend/x11/backend.c:478] X11 
does not support shared pixmaps 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - [backend/x11/backend.c:607] 
Failed to query DRI3 DRM FD 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - [src/main.cpp:134] Fatal error: 
Segmentation fault 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #1  0x363b40 <main+0x1580> at /
usr/local/bin/wayfire 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #2  0x82df1d53f 
<pthread_sigmask+0x53f> at /lib/libthr.so.3 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #3  0x82df1cafb 
<pthread_setschedparam+0x83b> at /lib/libthr.so.3 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #4  0x820bdc2d3 <???> at ??? 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #5  0x82210d5d4 
<wlr_backend_get_drm_fd+0x4> at /usr/local/wlroots016/lib
/libwlroots.so.11

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #6  0x362a3a <main+0x47a> at /
usr/local/bin/wayfire 

EE 20-02-24 08:44:06.531 - #7  0x82d23dafa 
<__libc_start1+0x12a> at /lib/libc.so.7
```

This is the content of the file wayfire.ini :

```
[alpha]
min_value = 0.100000
modifier = <alt> <super>

[animate]
close_animation = zoom
duration = 400
enabled_for = (type equals "toplevel" | (type equals "x-or" & focusable equals true))
fade_duration = 400
fade_enabled_for = type equals "overlay"
fire_duration = 300
fire_enabled_for = none
fire_particle_size = 16.000000
fire_particles = 2000
open_animation = zoom
startup_duration = 600
zoom_duration = 500
zoom_enabled_for = none

[annotate]
clear_workspace = <alt> <super> KEY_C
draw = <alt> <super> BTN_LEFT
from_center = true
line_width = 3.000000
method = draw
stroke_color = \#FF0000FF

[autorotate-iio]
lock_rotation = false
rotate_down = <ctrl> <super> KEY_DOWN
rotate_left = <ctrl> <super> KEY_LEFT
rotate_right = <ctrl> <super> KEY_RIGHT
rotate_up = <ctrl> <super> KEY_UP

[autostart]
autostart_wf_shell = true
gamma = wlsunset
idle = swayidle before-sleep swaylock
notifications = mako
outputs = kanshi
#portal = /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal

#[background-view]
#command = mpv --loop=inf
#file =

[bench]
average_frames = 1
frames_per_update = 3
position = top_center

[blur]
blur_by_default = type is "toplevel"
bokeh_degrade = 1
bokeh_iterations = 15
bokeh_offset = 5.000000
box_degrade = 1
box_iterations = 2
box_offset = 1.000000
gaussian_degrade = 1
gaussian_iterations = 2
gaussian_offset = 1.000000
kawase_degrade = 8
kawase_iterations = 2
kawase_offset = 2.000000
method = kawase
saturation = 1.000000
toggle = none

[command]
#binding_launcher = <super> <shift> KEY_ENTER
binding_lock = <super> <shift> KEY_ESC
binding_logout = <super> KEY_ESC
binding_mute = KEY_MUTE
binding_screenshot = <ctrl> <alt> <shift> KEY_S
binding_screenshot_interactive = <ctrl> <alt> KEY_S
#binding_screenshot = KEY_PRINT
#binding_screenshot_interactive = <shift> KEY_PRINT
binding_terminal = <super> KEY_ENTER
#command_launcher = wofi
command_light_down = decrease_brightness.sh
command_light_up = increase_brightness.sh
command_lock = swaylock
command_logout = wlogout
command_mute = amixer set Master toggle
#command_screenshot = grim $(date '+%F_%T').webp
command_screenshot = cd ~/Screenshots; grim
#command_screenshot_interactive = slurp | grim -g - $(date '+%F_%T').webp
command_screenshot_interactive = cd ~/Screenshots; slurp | grim -g -
command_terminal = alacritty
command_volume_down = mixer vol -5
command_volume_up = mixer vol +5
repeatable_binding_light_down = KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN
repeatable_binding_light_up = KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP
repeatable_binding_volume_down = KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
repeatable_binding_volume_up = KEY_VOLUMEUP

[core]
background_color = \#1A1A1AFF
close_top_view = <super> KEY_Q | <alt> KEY_F4
focus_button_with_modifiers = false
focus_buttons = BTN_LEFT | BTN_MIDDLE | BTN_RIGHT
focus_buttons_passthrough = true
max_render_time = -1
plugins = alpha animate autostart command cube expo fast-switcher fisheye grid idle invert move oswitch place resize switcher vswitch window-rules wm-actions wobbly wrot zoom decoration
preferred_decoration_mode = server
vheight = 3
vwidth = 3
xwayland = true
xwayland_scale = 1

[crosshair]
line_color = \#FF0000FF
line_width = 2

[cube]
activate = <alt> <ctrl> BTN_LEFT
background = \#1A1A1AFF
background_mode = simple
cubemap_image =
deform = 0
initial_animation = 350
light = true
rotate_left = none
rotate_right = none
skydome_mirror = true
skydome_texture =
speed_spin_horiz = 0.020000
speed_spin_vert = 0.020000
speed_zoom = 0.070000
zoom = 0.100000

[dbus_interface]

[decoration]
active_color = \#2E3440FF
border_size = 4
button_order = minimize maximize close
font = sans-serif
ignore_views = none
inactive_color = \#353B49FF
title_height = 30

[expo]
background = \#1A1A1AFF
duration = 300
offset = 10
select_workspace_1 = KEY_1
select_workspace_2 = KEY_2
select_workspace_3 = KEY_3
select_workspace_4 = KEY_4
select_workspace_5 = KEY_5
select_workspace_6 = KEY_6
select_workspace_7 = KEY_7
select_workspace_8 = KEY_8
select_workspace_9 = KEY_9
toggle = <super>

[extra-gestures]
close_fingers = 20
move_delay = 500
move_fingers = 3

[fast-switcher]
activate = <alt> KEY_ESC
activate_backward = <alt> <shift> KEY_ESC
inactive_alpha = 0.700000

[fisheye]
radius = 450.000000
toggle = <ctrl> <super> KEY_F
zoom = 7.000000

[follow-focus]
change_output = true
change_view = true
focus_delay = 50
raise_on_top = true
threshold = 10

[force-fullscreen]
constrain_pointer = false
constraint_area = view
key_toggle_fullscreen = <alt> <super> KEY_F
preserve_aspect = true
transparent_behind_views = true
x_skew = 0.000000
y_skew = 0.000000

[grid]
duration = 300
restore = <super> KEY_DOWN | <super> KEY_KP0
slot_b = <super> KEY_KP2
slot_bl = <super> KEY_KP1
slot_br = <super> KEY_KP3
slot_c = <super> KEY_UP | <super> KEY_KP5
slot_l = <super> KEY_LEFT | <super> KEY_KP4
slot_r = <super> KEY_RIGHT | <super> KEY_KP6
slot_t = <super> KEY_KP8
slot_tl = <super> KEY_KP7
slot_tr = <super> KEY_KP9
type = crossfade

[idle]
cube_max_zoom = 1.500000
cube_rotate_speed = 1.000000
cube_zoom_speed = 1000
disable_on_fullscreen = true
dpms_timeout = -1
screensaver_timeout = 3600
toggle = none

[input]
click_method = default
cursor_size = 24
cursor_theme = default
disable_touchpad_while_mouse = false
disable_touchpad_while_typing = false
gesture_sensitivity = 1.000000
kb_capslock_default_state = false
kb_numlock_default_state = false
kb_repeat_delay = 400
kb_repeat_rate = 40
left_handed_mode = false
middle_emulation = false
modifier_binding_timeout = 400
mouse_accel_profile = default
mouse_cursor_speed = 0.500000
mouse_scroll_speed = 1.000000
natural_scroll = false
scroll_method = default
tap_to_click = true
touchpad_accel_profile = default
touchpad_cursor_speed = 0.000000
touchpad_scroll_speed = 1.000000
xkb_layout = it
xkb_model =
xkb_options =
xkb_rules = evdev
xkb_variant =

[input-device]
output =

[invert]
preserve_hue = false
toggle = <super> KEY_I

[join-views]

[keycolor]
color = \#000000FF
opacity = 0.250000
threshold = 0.500000

[mag]
default_height = 500
toggle = <alt> <super> KEY_M
zoom_level = 75

[move]
activate = <super> BTN_LEFT
enable_snap = true
enable_snap_off = true
join_views = false
quarter_snap_threshold = 50
snap_off_threshold = 10
snap_threshold = 10
workspace_switch_after = -1

[oswitch]
next_output = <super> KEY_O
next_output_with_win = <shift> <super> KEY_O

[output]
mode = auto
position = auto
scale = 1.000000
transform = normal

[place]
mode = center

[preserve-output]
last_output_focus_timeout = 10000

[resize]
activate = <super> BTN_RIGHT

[scale]
allow_zoom = false
bg_color = \#1A1A1AE6
duration = 750
inactive_alpha = 0.750000
interact = false
middle_click_close = false
spacing = 50
text_color = \#CCCCCCFF
title_font_size = 16
title_overlay = all
title_position = center
toggle = <super> KEY_P
toggle_all =

[scale-title-filter]
bg_color = \#00000080
case_sensitive = false
font_size = 30
overlay = true
share_filter = false
text_color = \#CCCCCCCC

[showrepaint]
reduce_flicker = true
toggle = <alt> <super> KEY_S

[simple-tile]
button_move = <super> BTN_LEFT
button_resize = <super> BTN_RIGHT
inner_gap_size = 5
keep_fullscreen_on_adjacent = true
key_focus_above = <super> KEY_K
key_focus_below = <super> KEY_J
key_focus_left = <super> KEY_H
key_focus_right = <super> KEY_L
key_toggle = <super> KEY_T
outer_horiz_gap_size = 0
outer_vert_gap_size = 0
tile_by_default = all

[switcher]
next_view = <alt> <shift> KEY_TAB
prev_view = <alt> KEY_TAB
speed = 500
view_thumbnail_scale = 1.000000

[vswipe]
background = \#1A1A1AFF
delta_threshold = 24.000000
duration = 180
enable_free_movement = false
enable_horizontal = true
enable_smooth_transition = false
enable_vertical = true
fingers = 4
gap = 32.000000
speed_cap = 0.050000
speed_factor = 256.000000
threshold = 0.350000

[vswitch]
background = \#1A1A1AFF
binding_down = <ctrl> <super> KEY_DOWN
binding_left = <ctrl> <super> KEY_LEFT
binding_right = <ctrl> <super> KEY_RIGHT
binding_up = <ctrl> <super> KEY_UP
binding_win_down = <ctrl> <shift> <super> KEY_DOWN
binding_win_left = <ctrl> <shift> <super> KEY_LEFT
binding_win_right = <ctrl> <shift> <super> KEY_RIGHT
binding_win_up = <ctrl> <shift> <super> KEY_UP
duration = 300
gap = 20
wraparound = false

[water]
activate = <ctrl> <super> BTN_LEFT

[windecor]
active_color = \#222222AA
border_size = 4
button_order = minimize maximize close
close_color = \#CC000077
font = sans-serif
ignore_views = none
inactive_color = \#333333DD
maximize_color = \#09FF0077
minimize_color = \#EDD40077
title_height = 24

[window-rules]

[winzoom]
dec_x_binding = <ctrl> <super> KEY_LEFT
dec_y_binding = <ctrl> <super> KEY_UP
inc_x_binding = <ctrl> <super> KEY_RIGHT
inc_y_binding = <ctrl> <super> KEY_DOWN
modifier = <ctrl> <super>
nearest_filtering = false
preserve_aspect = true
zoom_step = 0.100000

[wm-actions]
minimize = none
send_to_back = none
toggle_always_on_top = none
toggle_fullscreen = none
toggle_maximize = none
toggle_showdesktop = none
toggle_sticky = none

[wobbly]
friction = 3.000000
grid_resolution = 6
spring_k = 8.000000

[workarounds]
all_dialogs_modal = true
app_id_mode = stock
dynamic_repaint_delay = false

[workspace-names]
background_color = \#333333B3
display_duration = 500
font = sans-serif
position = center
show_option_names = false
text_color = \#FFFFFFFF

[wrot]
activate = <ctrl> <super> BTN_RIGHT
activate-3d = <shift> <super> BTN_RIGHT
invert = false
reset = <ctrl> <super> KEY_R
reset-one = <super> KEY_R
reset_radius = 25.000000
sensitivity = 24

[zoom]
modifier = <super>
smoothing_duration = 300
speed = 0.010000
```

I've attached some pictures to show you the errors I get when I run that command with and without xorg running :

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

Comment: Can you verify that Wayland is indeed your backend?  DRM and modesetting need to be enabled.  Line 3 of your ini reports the detected backend as X11

Comment: Before you make the switch, see: [Wayland Known Issues with NVIDIA driver](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/535.154.05/README/wayland-issues.html).  The adoption rate for NVIDIA users and wayland will catch up if and when wayland becomes the default and replaces X11.

Comment: multiple megabytes of camera photos really aren't as good as copied and pasted text…

Comment: Ask here: https://forums.freebsd.org/forums/display-servers.38/ and first check this: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/wayland-and-nvidia-february-2024.92385/